# PubNub JSON serialization code works in example project but not in my project

Tags: c#, json, serialization, pubnub, winamp

I am making a Winamp plugin with the single function of sending the details of the song being played over HTTP to a webpage.

It works like this: Winamp song event triggered -> check for new song -> publish to webpage using [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) (C# API).

So far I got to the stage where everything works exactly as it is supposed to, except for the **PubNub code which doesn't serialize the object I'm passing for publishing into JSON**. All I keep getting in the PubNub console is a mere `{}` - an empty JSON object.

A little background on the project structure:

[image: Project breakdown]

I am using [Sharpamp](https://github.com/Daniel15/Sharpamp/tree/master/Sharpamp) which is a custom library that enables making Winamp plugins with C#. I am also using the [PubNub C# API](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/csharp/3.3/PubNub-Messaging). The gen_notifier_cs project is the C++ plugin wrapper created by Sharpamp. notifier_cs is where all my code resides. The two other projects are self explanatory I assume. **I have referenced the PubNub API in notifier_cs, and also have referenced Sharpamp in both notifier_cs and PubNub API.**

So, the objects that need to get serialized are of a class `Song` as defined in Sharpamp:

```
    public class Song
{
    public string Title { get; internal set; }
    public string Artist { get; internal set; }
    public string Album { get; internal set; }
    public string Year { get; internal set; }
    public bool HasMetadata { get; internal set; }
    public string Filename { get; internal set; }
}
```

So let's say if I have a `song` object with song data in it, I would go `pubnub.publish("winamp_pipe", song);` to publish it and PubNub will automatically serialize the data into JSON. But that's just not working in **my** solution.

To test why it wasn't serializing, I copied that class to the [example code file](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/blob/master/csharp/3.3/PubNub-Messaging/Pubnub_Example.cs) in the PubNub API. Visual Studio changed the class to this (notice the public Song() method):

```
public class Song
{
    public Song() // VS added this method
    {
        return; // I added this otherwise it would not compile
    }

    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public bool HasMetadata { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

On the same example file I initiated a default song object with some values:

```
Song song = new Song();
song.Album = "albumname";
song.Artist = "artistname";
song.HasMetadata = true;
song.Title = "songtitle";
song.Year = "2012";
```

And published it: `pubnub.publish("winamp_pipe", song);` **and it worked!** I got the JSON object in the PubNub channel!

`{"Album":"albumname","Artist":"artistname","Filename":null,"HasMetadata":true,"Title":"songtitle","Year":"2012"}`

So, I tried replacing the "new" `Song` class with the original one defined in Sharpamp. I tried adding another class definition in the notifier_cs project but that clashes with the one in Sharpamp which I have to rely on. I have been trying so many things as far as I could come up with. Needless to say none prevailed. Still, all I get is an empty JSON object.

This is the code that does the serializing, within the publish method in the **PubNub API**. I will remind you this code works with the PubNub example files but not with my project:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
serializer.WriteObject(ms, objectToSerialize);
ms.Position = 0;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I have been pulling out my hair for the last day. I know this post is super long but I appreciate your input nonetheless.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hi Pilau!  Looking over your details now.

Comment: To get you started quickly on a working path, you can push an array of string values into a list, then join the list with a "," `comma`.  Then publish this comma delimited string `pubnub.publish("winamp_pipe", "song,title,year");`

Comment: Added Answer - see "Publishing Data: PubNub and C# Winamp Song Class"

Answer (score 1):

## Publishing Data: PubNub and C# Winamp Song Class

You already have the data stored in a `winamp_song` object instance.  If you attempt to serialize the `winamp_song` object instance, it will fail.  The serialization will fail if you pass in the `winamp_song` as the instance has non-serializable members.  The best way to proceed is for you to create a `Song class` that you own and define.  Define the member values in the `Song class` which will be delivered via PubNub. This way you can populate directly the values that are needed to publish to your subscribers.

```c
Song song = new Song();
song.Album = winamp_song.Album;
song.Artist = winamp_song.Artis;
song.HasMetadata = winamp_song.HasMetadata;
song.Title = winamp_song.Title;
song.Year = winamp_song.Year;
```

When you receive the Song data publish even on your subscriber, you will be able to receive deserialized data, populating the values into a new `Song class` instance.

### Song Class Defined Below

```c
public class Song {
    public Song() { return; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public bool HasMetadata { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

PubNub is the best method for communicating with installed copies of your Winamp plugin.

Comment: Why are the members of the original class non-serializable?

Comment: I'm still hoping to get an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, my "solution", since I am only using one class (the `Song` class, defined in the Sharpamp library) to publish values by, is manually constructing a JSON string:

```
pubnub.publish("winamp_pipe", "{\"Album\": \""+song.Album+"\",\"Artist\": \""+song.Artist+"\",\"HasMetadata\": \""+song.HasMetadata.ToString()+"\",\"Title\": \""+song.Title+"\",\"Year\": \""+song.Year+"\",\"Filename\": \""+song.Filename+"\"}");
```

It is not a solution to the problem itself but it serves the purpose of publishing the information as a JSON object (as long as you don't have any special characters that break the JSON structure in your data).

I am not marking this as an answer because it is not a solution to the real problem, only a temporary workaround...

Comment: Why are you escaping the JSON? Why are you not just passing a JSON object?